# How to get custom tooltips to work with svg paths using css

Tags: html, css, svg

I am trying to use custom tooltips on svg paths but for some reason I cannot get them to work. In the code below I have a span element with the tooltip working and a svg image below it where the tooltips will not work.  Hovering over the text outside the graphic (tooltip working in span) shows the custom styled tooltip I am trying to apply to the svg.
In each box in the svg I have a title tag that works in the hover state but that gives the bland browser title display, so I know how to do that but I am looking for something a bit better.
I have tried using the [data-tooltip] code and css as used on the span : data-tooltip=”Datatooltip in the svg path and rectangle but to no avail. Not sure if I have missed something really obvious or what I am attempting to do is possible or not. Any advice is welcome.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        [data-tooltip]{
         position: relative;
         cursor: default;
         
       }

       [data-tooltip]::after{
position: absolute;
width: 140px;
left: calc(50% - 70px);
bottom: 125%;
text-align: center;
box-sizing: border-box;
content: attr(data-tooltip);
color: white;
background: black;
padding: 8px;
border-radius: 10px;
font-size: 0.9em;
font-weight: bold;
visibility: hidden;
opacity: 0;
transform: translateY(10px);
transition: opacity 0.3s, transform 0.2s;

       }

       [data-tooltip]:hover::after{
opacity: 1;
visibility: visible;
transform: translateY(0);
       }
       center{
           margin-top: 100px;
       }
       #box{
           width: 400px;
       }
       .d1{
           margin-bottom: 50px;
       }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <center>
        <div class="d1">
    <span data-tooltip="Data-tooltip above the box">Tooltip working in span</span>
</div>
    <svg id="box" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 386 344">
        <g >
            
          <rect  x="0.5" y="0.5" width="385" height="343" fill="#fff" />
          
          <path   d="M737,158V500H353V158H737m1-1H352V501H738V157Z" transform="translate(-352 -157)"/>
        </g>

        <g id="box4">
          <rect  data-tooltip="Tooltip in the bottom right box" x="191.5" y="172.5" width="194" height="171" fill="#d1cbcb"/>
          <path  data-tooltip="Tooltip in the bottom right box"d="M737,330V500H544V330H737m1-1H543V501H738V329Z" transform="translate(-352 -157)"/>
          <title  >Title in the bottom right box</title>
        </g>
        <g id="box3">
          <rect x="0.5" y="0.5" width="194" height="171" fill="#d1cbcb"/>
          <path d="M546,158V328H353V158H546m1-1H352V329H547V157Z" transform="translate(-352 -157)"/>
          <title>Title in the top left box</title>
        </g>
        <g id="box2">
          <rect x="0.5" y="172.5" width="194" height="171" fill="#aaa9a9"/>
          <path d="M546,330V500H353V330H546m1-1H352V501H547V329Z" transform="translate(-352 -157)"/>
          <title>Title in the bottom left box</title>
        </g>

        <g id="box1" >
          <rect x="191.5" y="0.5" width="194" height="171" fill="#aaa9a9"/>
          <path d="M737,158V328H544V158H737m1-1H543V329H738V157Z" transform="translate(-352 -157)"/>
          <title>Title in top right box</title>
        </g>
      </svg>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Her is a link to what I have tried so far: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/atataylor/qgua7sek/3/)

Comment: Are SVGs replaced elements and therefore cannot have before or after pseudo elements? (I'm asking because that's my understanding, I don't absolutely know for sure).

Comment: Yes that is correct.  `::before` and `::after` only apply to HTML elements.

Comment: Ok thanks for the info guys, looks like I will need to do this in jQuery. Cheers